# DefaultPreparedStatement not serializable

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am building a webapp using Datastax driver and Cassandra 3.10, when I deploy to Tomcat and start it up I get an error stating that:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultPreparedStatement
```

even though I do not use that anywhere in the code, all of my Prepared Statements are of the form:

```
private transient PreparedStatement     selectAssetClassStmt;
selectAllAssetClassesStmt = cassandraDatasource.getSession().prepare("select code,description from  asset_class where code = ?");
```

Comment: Please add the complete class you are trying to serialize and the complete error stack trace.

Comment: Why is it a data member at all? It should be a local variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use plain Cassandra (without Spring Data), you should use the [`com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.@Transient` annotation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.2/com/datastax/driver/mapping/annotations/Transient.html) :

> Whenever this annotation is added on a field, the field will not be
>   mapped to any column (neither during reads nor writes).

```
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.Transient;
...
@Transient
private PreparedStatement selectAssetClassStmt;
```

Not directly the matter but why do you declare a `PreparedStatement` field ?
It should not be required, it is error prone and it could result to unexpected behavior as you don't know its state when you will use it later.

The `PreparedStatement` variable  should just be a local variable which the lifespan is a method that does an access to the database.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, regarding the use of PreparedStatement variable, the Webapp is using Spring with all prepared statements being created in what I call a StatementFactory, this factory is a singleton Spring bean so the statements only get prepared once. I originally had all prepared statements as local variable similar to how Spring JDBC would expect them but then I got a shed load of errors saying statements should only be prepared once

Comment: Hi, my setup is 
Cassandra 3.10,
DataStax driver 3.1.4
Tomcat 7.0.57
Java 1.8.1.131
Spring 4.3.2

All Prepared statements are created in a Spring bean ( Singleton ) as

     private transient PreparedStatement  insertStmt;

Stacktrace
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultPreparedStatement
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
 at

Comment: I think I have found it but not sure why. The statement factory returns a PreparedStatement but there are several where the Bind function does not recognize the ? placeholder eg. when using the Apache Lucerne Index Builder. In these cases the code uses the getQueryString method of PreparedStatement to get the query and then uses String.format to insert the bind varables, simply changing the statement factory to return the query string rather than a PreparedStatement does the trick